# Using PHP Curl to upload a file to resmush.it API

Tags: php, curl

I'm building an automated click & optimize file uploader for a simple utility that I'm building, and I want to use the resmush.it API to optimize the uploaded images.

The upload part works just fine, but I'm struggling with the "resmush" part. This is the code that I'm using:

```
<?php
// $file is the complete path for the uploaded file
function resmush($file)
{
    $header = ['Content-Type: multipart/form-data'];

    $curlCall = curl_init("http://api.resmush.it/ws.php?qlty=90");
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
        'files' => curl_file_create($file)
    ]);
    $result = curl_exec($curlCall);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    curl_close($curlCall);

    print_r($result);
}
```

Now, actually the file is loaded to resmush.it but the `$result` array contains a 401 error instead of an optimized image path.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [src] => http://static0.resmush.it/output/f8b0506cb2c33fd250cd7554af60b361/compare_2_original.jpg
    [host] => static0.resmush.it
    [filename] => compare_2_original.jpg
    [token] => 439466ec87fc37bff74ebc3d87cca407
    [error] => 401
    [error_long] => Cannot copy from remote url
    [generator] => reSmush.it rev.1.4.22.20170224
    [remote_server] => static2.resmush.it
)
```

I have no clue about what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Show the $file var.

Comment: It's `/var/www/test-uploader/tmp/compare_2_original.jpg` (where the file is actually present)

Comment: Take a look at allow_url_fopen  in .ini

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` It's set to `true`

Comment: `[error_long] => Cannot copy from remote url`

Comment: According to the documentation here http://www.resmush.it/api, the extended error is "401 : impossible to fetch the image from URL (usually a local URL)". But the image seems to be correctly loaded and if you look at the `result`'s src, you will see the original image that I've uploaded...